# forEach em javascript para um retorno em json com erro para um unico registro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um problema bem chato e não sei o motivo

Através de uma requisição ajax, eu pego do servidor as notificações que o usuário ainda não visualizou (parecido com o facebook)
Para isso, eu uso o seguinte código:

```
$.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL+"ajax/getNotifications",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            var resultHTML = '';
            response.forEach(function(result)
            {
                resultHTML += '<a href="'+result.href+'" class="no-ajaxy">\n' +
                    '                <div class="user-box">\n' +
                    '                    <div class="user-foto"></div>\n' +
                    '                    <div class="name">'+result.titulo+'</div>\n' +
                    '                    <div class="mail">'+result.mensagem+'</div>\n' +
                    '                </div>\n' +
                    '                </a>';
            });
            $("#justA").hide().html(resultHTML).fadeIn("slow");

        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error + " -  teste");
        }
    });
```

Ele funciona corretamente quando o resultado em json trás mais de UMA notificação (que é adicionada dinamicamente como podem ver)

Porém quando só trás uma única notificação, tenho o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: response.forEach is not a function

Não sei se no javascript é diferente, mas no PHP por exemplo, o foreach funciona se tiver um ou mais elementos, porém em js parece funcionar apenas quando realmente tem mais de um elemento
O que pode ser feito? obrigado

---

retorno em que o forEach não funciona:

```
{"href":"javascript:void(0)","titulo":"Sem notifica\u00e7\u00f5es!","mensagem":"Atualmente voc\u00ea n\u00e3o possu\u00ed notifica\u00e7\u00f5es"}
```

Retorno em que ele funciona:

```
[{"href":"\/navegar","titulo":"teste horario 04:09","mensagem":"TESTE HORARIO 04:09"},{"href":"pregao\/ativos\/detalhes\/6","titulo":"Preg\u00e3o Finalizado!","mensagem":"Seu preg\u00e3o foi finalizado, confira!"}]
```

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/273649/edit) a pergunta e coloque o retorno, para assim alguém te ajudar.

Comment: @wmsouza editei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O **[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** é uma função de um elemento `Array`. `Json` pode retornar um `array`. Ex:

```
[{"nome": "Valdeir"},{"nome": "Psr"}]`
```

mas também pode retornar um `object`. Ex:

```
{"nome": "Valdeir"}`
```

No seu caso, ele está retornando **um** elemento, mas como *objeto*. No seu *back-end* é necessário que você faça uma verificação.

**Lógica:**

```
Se a variável resultado possuir mais de um valor então
    retorna todos como um array
Senão
    cria um array e retorna ele
fim se
```

Comment: Acabei notando que é exatamente isso, com um elemento apenas o php está retornando um objeto e não um array, vou verificar, obrigado!